# Pass windows credentials from angular 13 to core 6

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I m using Angular 13 as frontEnd and Core 6 as backEnd for my Project. I want to use windows authentication in my project.
My angular app is running on different port as of Core 6, so bith are hosted on IIS seperatly.
I'm passing the windows credentials from angular app but on Core 6 it does not read it. Below is the code and config used.

Angular 13

Http interceptor..
i intercept HTTP request and pass the windows credentials..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpEvent
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class WinAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
  constructor(){}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   req = req.clone({
    withCredentials: true
  });

    return next.handle(req);
 }
}
```

App.module.ts file.. I have registered my inteceptor in app module

```
providers: [HttpService, {
provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
useClass: WinAuthInterceptor,
multi: true
  }],
```

App.component.ts where HTTP call is made..

```
GetUser(){

  this.httpService.GetData('Main/GetData').subscribe((val: any) => {

  console.log(val)
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

HTTPService.ts file

```
GetData(url: string, params?: HttpParams, headers?: HttpHeaders) {
    if (params != null) {
      this.httpOptions.params = params;
    }
    if (headers != null) {
      this.httpOptions.headers = headers;
    }
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + url, this.httpOptions);
}
```

ASP.NET Core 6 app configurations..

Program.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;
using RXO.EDI.Applications.DAL;
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
    builder
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    //.AllowAnyOrigin();
    .AllowCredentials()
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://UATserver.pvt:9023");
}));

var app = builder.Build();

ConfigurationHelper.LoadAppSettingsFile();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
//app.UseStaticFiles();

//app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.Run();
```

IIS Setup.. My applications are hosted on 2 different websites as below

[image]

For Application app. I have enabled anonymous auth as true and windows auth as true so that HTTP OPTIONS would be able to pass the auth without windows credentials.

[image]

For ApplicationsUI I have disabled anonymous auth as false and windows auth as true. It popups an windows auth then I enter my windows credentials.

[image]

MainControllerApi.cs file

```
[Route("GetData")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetData()
        {
            string userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            string envUsrName = Environment.UserName;
            string usr = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

            string currentUserId = User.Identity.Name;
            //ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);

            Set("UserRole", "List of Role", null);
            Set("UserRole", "List of Role", null);

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
            string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];


            return userName + " - " + envUsrName + " - " + usr + " - " + username + " - " + _user;
        }
```

When I try to getUserName via Angular http call, it fails.

[image]

[image]

I got stuck here. Could anyone point me where I'm going wrong.